# Consulta com select e find no rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Olá, eu queria fazer um find com select de apenas alguns campos no rails, porém está dando erro, porém, se faço com where ele funciona normalmente, alguém sabe se é possível usar o select com o find?
Ex:

```
@organization = Organization.find(actual_organization.id).select(:required_project_type, :required_folder_type)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça da seguinte forma:

```
@organization = Organization.find(actual_organization.id, :select => [:required_project_type, :required_folder_type])
```